# Editing user information within the app gives me an error with Parse

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I get an error saying this:

**This User is not allowed to add a field to _User. You can change this setting in the Data Browser.**

From testing, it seems that this only affects users signed in through Facebook. I don't really know what setting the error is talking about.

The code isn't doing anything that special. The weird part is it used to work before. It is only recently that it started to throw an error.

```
currUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currUser.put("username", username);//username
currUser.put("email", email);//email
currUser.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Without seeing relevant code snippets, tracking down your issue is nigh impossible.

Comment: edited to add some code, but it is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It seems like the setting for Add Field wasn't public in the _User class under security.